# change the "save image as..." name of images produced by an http handler in .net

Tags: .net, image, httphandler, save-as

I have a series of images stored in a MySQL database that I am displaying with a .NET Http handler (showImage.ashx).  If the user right clicks on an image and selects "save image as...", the image name always defaults to 'showImage.jpg'.  I have potential image names saved in the database, is there any way to control the default save name of an image through the http handler?

Adding a Content-Disposition header was the solution, thanks so much!

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","filename=" + fileName + ";");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You need to add a `Content-Disposition` header](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheContentDispositionSagaControllingTheSuggestedFileNameInTheBrowsersSaveAsDialog.aspx), like this:

```
Content-Disposition: filename=Something.jpg
```